# how to return the selected Item in the list and not the last Item in the list using Pyqt5 in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have a code that display Items in a QlistWidget that refer to a file path once the user select any file the **system return the last Item only.**

What i need is to return the selected item only.

so that the user will be able to select any item no matter where it exist.

example :

- C:\Users\test\Desktop\New Microsoft Word Document.docx row =>0
- C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_arabic.docx row =>1

In the function below i am trying to iterate over the items in the QlistWidget

1. Get the **full path of the file (from root)**
2. Split the path
3. Add the rest of the path based on the **index**

but this did not work because sometimes the displayed files in the list are from different folder therefor have different path.

## code:

```
def FileListSelected(self):             # Function to select the desired file from the list in the left pane
        ListIterator=range(self.listWidgetPDFlist.count())
        try:
            index = 0   
            for index in ListIterator:
                p = pathlib.Path(self.fullPath)
                print("this is P==>{}".format(p))
                oneDir = os.path.join(*p.parts[:-2])
                print("this is oneDir==>{}".format(oneDir))            
                Item= oneDir + "\\" + self.listWidgetPDFlist.selectedItems()[index].text()
                print("this is the cuurent Item =={}".format(Item))            
                ppp=os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), Item) 

                print("this is ppp==>{}".format(ppp))
                print("===============================================")
                index =+1
                print("index =>".format(index))
                self.mouseHover()
                return ppp
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the text of the selected item from the list.  To do that use:

```
self.listWidgetPdfList.selectedItems()[0].text()
```

Here you use 0 as the index because you want only the first item in the selected items list.  Iterating through the list is unnecessary if you only want the selected item.

Comment: i tried your answer but still the same problem ... i will edit my question and add what i did and the returned result